# How to separate the first string before @";" in an Array?

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to split a string in an array:

```
NSString *test = @"How are you;<random>[Good;Bad]";
NSArray *howareyou = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]
```

But then it splits `<random>[Good` and `Bad]`...

I just want to split the `How are you` and `<random>[Good;Bad]`

How can I do this??

Comment: It’d help if you stated what exactly are the rules you need when splitting by `;`. Is it _always_ the first `;` only?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *test = @"How are you;<random>[Good;Bad]"; 
NSRange colonRange = [test rangeOfString:@";"];
if (colonRange.location != NSNotFound){
    NSString *firstHalf = [test substringToIndex:colonRange.location];
    NSString *secondHalf = [test substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(colonRange)];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", firstHalf, secondHalf);
}else{
    NSLog(@"No luck");
}
```

Comment: Or this. Even better.  My lisp is sometimes noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *test = @"How are you;<random>[Good;Bad]";
NSArray *howareyou = [test componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

NSString *desired = [howareyou objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *rest = [[howareyou subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [howareyou count]-1)]
                        componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
```

Doesn't get much less efficient (or brittle -- no error checking, range checking, length checking, etc...) than that.  Perfectly fine for a few strings here and there of limited length, probably unacceptable for large input and the like.

Measure first.  Optimize after.